# How to break (stop with an error) a stream-based download in browser

Tags: php, http, browser, streaming, silex

In our app (PHP) users can download files, which content is based on a data from db. This data can be very big (gigs), so we start streaming file right away while generating it (includes processing data). Thus, we are unable to set Content-Length, cause we don't know it yet. Of course, some exceptions are possible, first of all db (mongo to be exact) timeout or connection loss, or something in data-to-content processing, or smth else. Now if exception occurs, from the users point of view, downloading simply stops (as if it is finished). That is very unpleasant for us, as user may think that the download was a success, but in reality the file contains 10 000 lines instead of 20 000. So we'd like to break the stream in such a way, that browser would show 'error' on download. Currently, the streaming is handled by Silex as it is described in docs (http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/master/usage.html#streaming), but we can switch no native php instruments, if it matters. Googling haven't helped much yet, but probably i'm using wrong keywords. So the question is: is it possible, and if so, how? Language is a second case, the most important here is a general approach it terms of http, i think.

Comment: You should send a `Content-Length` header, so that the browser can determine if a download was successful or not.

Comment: I don't know the content-length, as the file is being generated and streamed at the same time. I can only guess it approximately, but it seems like a last option workaround at best..

Comment: Instead of directly streaming, you should save the file and then stream it. After you're done with streaming, you can always delete the file.

Comment: I guess I've made a bad description. The files can be very big. Several gigabytes for instance. We can't store those file beforehand (just trust me), and making user wait while we generate the giant file and only then start streaming it is not an option. The user clicks on 'download' and expects that download starts right away.

Comment: If you neither can save the file nor know beforehand how big the file is gonna be, there is no way how the browser can tell if the download is successful.

Comment: That is the difference. It already assumes that it is successful. I need to tell it that something 'went wrong' like 'the stream is broken' or smth. like that. So, what you're telling me, is that the only way the browser understands that there's been an error, is by comparing the provided length with actual size after the stream is dead, and there is no option to 'signal' it?